# <kbd> tag is messed when it got five characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, kbd

While cleaning the new and incorrect (in my opinion) [vb](/questions/tagged/vb) tag from Stack Overflow today, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483381/converting-keypress-event-from-vb6-to-vb-net) which had "Enter" that I wanted to format using `<kbd>` tags.

So I did and that's what I saw:

> > [image]

Horrified I went to perform some quick tests and found that whenever `<kbd>` tag contain five characters it will span two lines:

<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Break</kbd> <kbd>12345</kbd>

Less or more are OK:

<kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> <kbd>123456</kbd>

Saw some weird things, but this has a place of honor. :)

I found a way around by injecting three fancy space characters:

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

But it feels pretty hacky.

Browser: Chrome 21 - totally forgot I chose to install Beta versions whenever they are ready. :(

Comment: `no-repro` for me (Safari 5.1.6/OS X)

Comment: It's not broken for me... Chrome 20

Comment: Browser? And don't dare to say it is not an official released one...

Comment: This may be related to [this Canary bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130724) I posted a while back.

Comment: @Urist aka Bobby - blonde moment on my part.. the browser updates are so transparent I completely forgot I'm on Beta version of Chrome 21.

Comment: @Manish cheers, looks like you are right on spot - if this question is to survive please post this as an answer. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Well, I dunno--the bare bones styling I mentioned over there doesn't seem to work. Looks like it's a similar bug, but with different causes. I'll post it as an answer anyway.

Comment: I put in a fix for this. it will be in the next prod build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a similar bug in Canary a while back.

[Here's the bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130724); apparently it was fixed.

I'll mess around with the styling till I can figure out what's wrong.